# Check if child view of RecyclerView item is visible on screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a scenario in which I need to know if a child view of a RecyclerView item is visible on screen.

In this case, each RecyclerView item has a `TextView` and I need to know if that TextView is fully visible on screen. I've already figured this part out, but now my question is this:

**How can I make a call to the adapter from my fragment to let it know that the view is visible on screen? What best practice should I follow for this?**

Here is my fragment class method where I get the visible child view:

```
    private void getFirstVisibleChildView() {
        int findFirstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int findLastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

        int [] positions = { findFirstVisibleItemPosition, findLastVisibleItemPosition };

        PostAdapter.PostViewHolder viewHolder;

        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        recyclerView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);

        int[] location = new int[2];
        for (int position : positions) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder item = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);

            if (item instanceof PostAdapter.PostViewHolder) {
                viewHolder = (PostAdapter.PostViewHolder) item;

                viewHolder.getChildView().getLocationInWindow(location);

                if (location[1] < 0 || location[1] > scrollBounds.bottom) {
                    // Not visible
                } else {
                    // Visible
                    // How to call the RecyclerView adapter here and be able to manipulate it?
                    // Custom listener, direct call to ViewHolder, or some other method?
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you wanna do if it is visible?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `addOnScrollListener` on the RecyclerView, so it checkes if your specific view is fully shown whenever it's scrolled

And normally create a custom method in your adapter that you want to call within this listener when the above condition is met.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (mRecyclerViewTafsir.getLayoutManager() == null) return;

        // Here you can check if the particular textView is fully 
        // appeared on the screen >> You already did this part
        
        mAdapter.callBack(); // call a method in the adapter when the condition is met
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that makes a call to the adapter, but not for a specific item in the adapter. How would that be done?

Comment: @user4165123 I think you need to call `getFirstVisibleChildView()`  while scrolling the `recyclerView`, and check if you fall in the `else` branch inside this method .. `getFirstVisibleChildView() ` should be aware of the first visible item isn't it?